# I'm getting "invalid cast exception handled" instead of the message box that I tried to have show up on the screen

Tags: visual-studio

My goal here is to get a message that says something like "Enter a number" when i type a a letter into a calculator but, the problem is that instead of using the IsNumeric function that I wrote, it says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll."
I have option strict on and it has to stay on. The code for the calculate button is below. The nested Ifs i was trying to do were there so that it would indicate that only positive numbers and what is valid would work. What's keeping the message box from showing up. The place that 'System.InvalidCastException' shows up is next to intRadius = CInt(txtInputRadiusValue.Text)

```
 Private Sub btnCalculateArea_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateArea.Click
    Dim intRadius As Integer
    intRadius = 0
    Dim intVolume As Integer
    intVolume = 0
    Const dblPi As Double = 3.14159
    Dim strNumber As String
    strNumber = "String.Empty"

    If intRadius >= 0 Then
        If IsNumeric(strNumber) Then
            'To make the contents of the textbox what the radius equals
            intRadius = CInt(txtInputRadiusValue.Text)
        Else

            MessageBox.Show("The number you have enterd is invalid. Please enter a number that is valid.")

        End If
        'To compute the Volume of a Sphere
        intVolume = CInt(1.333 * dblPi * (intRadius ^ 3))
            'To display the answer in a label
            lblRectangularBox.Text = CType(intVolume, String)





        Else


        If intRadius < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You can't use negative numbers for this calculator. Please enter a number that is not a negative.")
        Else

        End If

    End If






End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in your instantiation:

```
strNumber = "String.Empty"

    If intRadius >= 0 Then
        If IsNumeric(strNumber) Then
            'To make the contents of the textbox what the radius equals
            intRadius = CInt(txtInputRadiusValue.Text)
        Else

            MessageBox.Show("The number you have enterd is invalid. Please enter a number that is valid.")

        End If
```

I may be wrong, but when you do your If IsNumeric, it seems to me you have not yet let the user input his/her value yet. Why not instantiate the `strNumber = "0"`?

I think that might fix your problem. The MSDN documentation states that the IsNumeric function also returns True if Expression is a Char or String ***that can be successfully converted to a number***. Since they don't say anything about empty string values, I would stay away from those.

Hope that helps.